# $injector.get('$http') and $httpProvider throw Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs

I have a wrapper problem before each request (add a header with the value X-CSRF-TOKEN) and response (get a new X-CSRF-TOKEN token)

But I came across a mistake:

```
Error: $ injector: unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $ httpProviderProvider <- $ httpProvider <- HttpPreConfigController <- LoginService
```

Authorization module:

```
var appAuth = angular.module("app-auth", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", "ngCookies"]);
```

Controller:

```
appAuth.controller("LoginController", function ($scope, $timeout, $window, $rootScope, LoginService) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        LoginService.getUser().then(function (response) {
            ...
        });
    };
});
```

Service:

```
appAuth.factory("LoginService", function ($resource, $route, $cookieStore, $q, $rootScope, HttpPreConfigController) {
    var LoginService;

    LoginService = {
        getUser: function () {
            return HttpPreConfigController.get('/rest/user');
        }
    };
    return LoginService;
});
```

and the wrapper:

```
appAuth.factory('HttpPreConfigController', ['$injector', '$cookieStore', '$httpProvider', function ($injector, $cookieStore, $httpProvider) {
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
    $http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data, headers) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookieStore.get('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
    });
    $http.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (data, headers) {
        $cookieStore.put("X-CSRF-TOKEN", headers('X-CSRF-TOKEN'));
    });
    return $http;
}]);
```

Can you get rid of this error?

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because **Providers** are only injectable to the config phase of your app. So you should move your code from `factory` to a `config` block for this to work. Hope this will help.